# conditionals: "...といったら、...." vs. "...というなら、..."?

Tags: word-choice, conditionals

> (1)「元気そうだと田中さんが**いったら**、信用できる証拠と思う。」
>
> (2) 「元気そうだと田中さんが**いうなら**、信用できる証拠と思う。」

Are both grammatically correct?

Were I to want to say:

> If Tanaka-san were to say that **X** appears to be in good health, then I think that that is evidence that you can trust to be true.

Are both #1 and #2 correct with regard to meaning?
Which sounds natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example...

> 1) 田中さんがそう言っ**たら**、信用するよ。
>   2) 田中さんがそう言う**なら**、信用するよ。

＃1 means "If Tanaka-san says/said so, I will/would trust that." (Tanaka-san may or may not say so). ＃2 can mean the same, but it sounds more like "Since Tanaka-san says so, I trust that." (Tanaka-san actually said that.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a difference in conditionals (had to look up what subjunctive mood meant).

たら　has the nuance of "if he has said that". Extrapolating from that, the tone here is like:
{if this has happened/X has done Y, then "something".}

なら -> というなら　here has the nuance of "if **he** says that". More generally, the tone is:
{if this is the case/if things are like this/that}

They are both usuable...if I was pressed to say なら　feels more subjective and appropriate if the speaker is highly evaluating the truth-worthiness of that person, or was previously suspicious of that fact or other witnesses.

たら　feels more objective and a reflection of the current situation, and what the speaker and who they are talking to should do next.